# Neo4j/Cypher delete node and childs with relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to delete node (64) with child nodes (65, 66, 67) and relationships from this graph:
[Graph image](https://mtlxpq.bn1301.livefilestore.com/y2pnDzBUfbFO2gm3GFXMsAUVuXmxdF-bKPSLBghKd8JTOOb4sEdDZywdRMaha66RpXw0_R2CzqAM23CMPTvsuhf2-6K7nkwZEOqxXpAKGD8iaBFyAmjZXDEWDudmVKi1algHiIOGTzzeD4_13XRDArehQ/Lomogram_2014-12-26_09-21-53-AM.jpg?psid=1)

```
start n=node(64)
match (e)-[r]->(n)
match (n)-[r2*]->(e2)
delete r
foreach (rel in r2| delete rel)
DELETE n, e2
```

Get exception:

```
javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException: Failed to commit transaction Transaction(1336, owner:"qtp1613738960-605")[STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION,Resources=1], transaction rolled back ---> Node record Node[66,used=false,rel=141,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships
```

How change query for fix it?

Comment: Your node still seems to have other relationships, not just to n (transitively) you might also end up with other orphaned nodes along the chain from n to e2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no cypher expert but you can only delete nodes with no relationships and your exception clearly states that node 66 still has relationships. The problem is, that you do not delete the incoming relationships (the ones that come from the left) on 65, 66, 67.

I would try something like this:

```
START n=node(64) /*Select start node*/
MATCH ()-[r1]->(n) /*Select all incoming relationships for start node*/
MATCH (n)-[*]->(o) /*Select "outgoing" nodes at any depth*/
MATCH ()-[r2]->(o) /*Select all incoming relationships for "o", ie node 65,66,67*/
DELETE r1,r2,n,o
```

By the way if you just want to delete a collection of nodes/relationships you do not need to use `foreach`. A simple `delete` will do just fine.